# kml/kmz files not loading by google maps anymore

Tags: openstreetmap, google-maps, kml, overlay

Until a few months ago this worked: https://maps.google.com/maps?q=http://www.jcea.es/pics/italia2015/italia2015.kmz

It is NOT working anymore.

I know that I can login in Google maps, create a custom map and upload a KML file (if it has less than 2.000 points, my KML files are far bigger). But I don't want to upload a KML file, I want a map I can overlay a KML hosted in my HTTP/HTTPS server.

In fact I rather prefer to use something like OpenStreetMap instead of Google, but I don't know any service I could use.

Comment: needs to be a kml but leaflet http://harrywood.co.uk/maps/examples/leaflet/kml.view.html will load points, line and polygons but not network links, super overlayers etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can:

- Create your own solution with `Leaflet` http://leafletjs.com/ and one of the plugins from a list below http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#overlay-data
- Use http://umap.openstreetmap.fr/ with external data overlay. Check layers. It's not as easy as paste a link into google map search, but much more power-full.
  Yuo could upload your data or use a link to external file or files.
- Use http://share.mapbbcode.org/ you still need to upload your kml/kmz but after that you could export created map in html and use it on your own site. It's easier than umap, but not as power-full.
- If there are only points in your dataset, you may convert them into GeoJSON or csv and use http://geojson.io